# I get System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load the specified file.' when creating the composition container on .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

I use Kephas Framework and the problem arises when creating the MEF composition container, like in the example below:

```
        var ambientServicesBuilder = new AmbientServicesBuilder();
        IAppManager appManager = null;
        var appContext = new AppContext();
        var elapsed = await Profiler.WithStopwatchAsync(
            async () =>
                {
                    await ambientServicesBuilder
                            .WithNLogManager()
                            .WithNetAppRuntime()
                            // the next line triggers the exception
                            .WithMefCompositionContainerAsync();

                    appManager = ambientServicesBuilder.AmbientServices.CompositionContainer.GetExport<IAppManager>();
                    await appManager.InitializeAppAsync(appContext);
                });
```

It seems that "Kephas.Core.resources" is not found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems not to show up on the .NET 4.5 Framework. A workaround is provided below, make sure to place it before initializing the ambient services:

```
        AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += (context, name) =>
            {
                if (name.Name.EndsWith(".resources"))
                {
                    return null;
                }

                // do other stuff, like throwing exceptions.
                return null;
            };
```

Note that this will disable the exception at runtime, however at design time it will still be thrown but without affecting the program execution.